# Re-enter pdb after ssh disconnected

Tags: python, debugging, ssh, pdb

I ssh'ed to a remote server and ran a deep learning Python program. I had some `pdb` break point once the training is over. But after maybe 30 mins, my ssh connection was cut off by the server due to no activity. Now I re-ssh'ed to the server and saw the Python program still running. Highly possible it finished the training and had hit my `pdb` break point. How can I re-attach or re-enter to the pdb console? Thank you ~!

Comment: Might be a bit too late now. You could try to attach gdb instead. But, as far as I know, pdb has no solution for that.

Comment: Presumably the Python interpreter is actually still running pdb. If so, if you could reattach to that process's stdio, you'd be right back in pdb.

Comment: Thank you abarnert for the prompt reply. What is a good way to `reattach to that process's stdio` ?

Comment: Strongly suggest using screen.  You're probably out of luck this time, but if you'd used screen, `screen -r` would reattach, and you could still see your python process.